# Restricting hibernate queried data based upon the owning group of a user

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, multi-tenant

The standard example is probably where you offer a service to multiple companies on the same hosted instance and want employees to be able to see data only from other employees of the same company, not of potentially competitive companies.

I'm using JBossAS7 with Hibernate 4.x.

I *could* push the company information down from the UI layer and have the (stateless) persistence layer filter on that, but it seems like a bad idea to me, I'd rather have it done in one place closer to the database.

I'm guessing there must be a standard, secure solution for this, maybe around security domains or hibernate sessions? Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be building a "multi-tenant application". Hibernate's support for multi-tenancy is quite restricted at the moment, with feature [request 5697](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5697) having been recently completed, in 4.0.0.Alpha2. Note that this feature request does not address addition of tenant discriminator columns in the entities, which going by the discussion in JIRA, would arrive in 4.0.0.Alpha3 or [4.1.0](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6054) (going by JIRA). At the moment, you can store the data related to various tenants in different databases or schemas.

You can also read this [related blog post](http://relation.to/Bloggers/MultitenancyInHibernate), on various options regarding achieving multi-tenancy in Hibernate; this is quite old compared to the work done in HHH-5697, and does not discuss how one would create a multi-tenant application with tenant discriminator columns in the entity model.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I'm after. I'll keep an eye on the latest 4.x releases. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, if you are using JPA, note that EclipseLink already supports [multitenancy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Multitenant).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of any standard, but have worked on two systems where it was important. These pre-dated tools like Hibernate and our use of J2EE.

In all systems I've worked on we've had to code this ourselves - using company as part of our keys in requests.

One possibility is a whole different "whatever your database calls its partition" for each customer. (Schema if you're in Oracle). Sounds more complex but it does guarantee isolation between companies and it does also allow some management of scaling or new/delete company. In my previous place of work I remember legal types felt nervous if anyone mentioned keeping more than one company's data in the same table - so that kept them happy.

You could either have your app server connect to the database as a trusted user who can access all, or make sure you pass the end user's credentials down when you connect. I've heard of this. It sounds good from a security point of view and means in a database like Oracle the right thing will just happen. I've not seen it done and wonder how well connection pooling would work if at all.

Edit: Vineet's answer above seems to cover it well. It's an area I'll have to look at more. We've probably got too much legacy code here to change.